# Updates to the on-topic page (4/23/2020)

Tags: discussion, on-topic

We've had a recent spam attack that resulted in an overwhelming number of links to medium articles, blogs, and other unreliable information sources.

(We're asking users to be extra vigilant until we can get this cleaned up--**please flag any spam like content for moderator deletion.**)

We've also added two important new guidelines in our [on-topic page](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Answers with cut-and-paste content and no additional context or explanation will be deleted, even if you cite the source & provide a link. We encourage citation from reliable sources, but answerers are expected to (at least) describe in their own words the reason for the excerpt, and why it answers or comments on the question.
>
> Don't post content to primarily promote yourself, blogs, articles, or source code. StackExchange is a Q&A site, where good questions ideally receive more than one well founded answer.